# How to open a XAML file outside of VS2010 with a XAML editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, editor, workflow

I am having errors loading a xaml file into workflow designer, I read somewhere that if I open this XAML file in the XAML editor the ~ squigly signs might help debug the issue.  However my XAML file is not included in any project or solution file within VS2010.  I can't find XAMLPAD anywhere on my system although I have VS2010.   I just need to be able to open my XAML file outside the VS2010. How do I that? There should be a xaml editor somewhere on Windows7. Right?

Please HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XamlPad doesn't necessarily come with Visual Studio, it comes with version 6.0A of the Windows SDK. A quick google for XamlPad will give you the following link with all the information you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742398(v=vs.90).aspx

**EDIT**

It turns out that it is really hard to get hold of the Windows SDK 6.0A unless you have an MSDN subscription. It also turns out that XamlPad has been discontinued after .NET 3.5.

A quick google turns up a few results... this one looks quite good, but results may vary:
http://kaxaml.com/

Comment: Thank  you, I had seen that link as well.  However I don't have V6.0 on my machine. Is there any other xaml editor that you can think of?  Actually I found the name of XAMLPad from the exact same link.